# Lost a desktop folder

Tags: filesystem, directory

I am pretty new to Linux and was trying to change the name of a desktop folder from Documents to Media when I got an error message about the pathway.  I restarted the computer and lost the folder.  I have followed some of the suggestions posted and got the following message using `sudo ls /home/bob`:

```
2014-05-26-213012_1440x900_scrot.png  MEDIA
CryptoHeavenClient.properties         Music
Desktop                   Public
dictionaries                  Templates
Downloads                 WNA1100_DriverOnly_1.2.0.2_signed
```

Using `ls -la`, I found the following listing:

```
drwxr-xr-x 14 bob  bob    4096 Jan 26 10:55 MEDIA
```

I think the folder is still there with the data but I could really use some help in getting it back.  Thanks!

Comment: Seems like the `Documents` directory has been renamed as `MEDIA`, the permissions are also all right, all the data should be Ok. What command you have used to rename and what was the exact error message? And what you really want to get back?

Comment: Check if your documents exist in `MEDIA` by `ls ~/MEDIA`?

Comment: THANK YOU!  The data files are showing up with that command.  I have lots of family photos in there-was backing up prior to burning to CD.  I tried to change the name of the folder by right clicking and using the properties dialog instead of the rename dialog.  That's when it disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

For me also, suddenly all the folders in the desktop disappeared. Also I cant able to open the folders. When I inserted the pendrive, I got the message as "Unable to open the folder. No application is registered as handling this file". What to do???